# Is "I was wondering" a complete sentence?

Tags: grammar

My instinct tells me it is not.  It is a sentence fragment which needs some sort of noun clause to complete it.

But I'm being outnumbered by a number of posters on a language platform I belong to, which gives me pause.  Also, someone on Quora has insisted that it ***is*** a complete sentence.

I did search through the questions already submitted regarding this phrase, and did not find an answer.

Comment: It could be used as a complete sentence, but normally would require more. "Why did you ask that?" — "I was just wondering." But that's rare. You'd at least expect something like "I was wondering about that." But we need to know the context. Technically, it is a complete sentence.

Comment: The complement of "wondering" is elided, but it could still stand alone in an appropriate context.

Comment: It has a subject and a verb (and this verb does not strictly require an object) and the verb conjugation matches the subject.  That's all that's required for an English sentence to be grammatically correct and complete in a strict sense, although not every grammatically complete sentence is going to be *clear* or very *meaningful*.

Comment: And it has a tensed verb, i.e. "was".

Comment: @stangdon That is very much not true. Some words (often verbs) have a mandatory valence, i. e. *must* be complemented with another word. You cannot use a transitive verb without an object, for instance. "I said" or "I bought" are not complete sentences. Some verbs, like "give", even have two mandatory valences - "I gave" is not a complete sentence, it has to be "I gave the book (direct object) to my friend (indirect object)" to be a complete sentence.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are saying is not true?  Are you saying that because the verb "was wondering" does not meet the mandatory valence rule, it is in fact not a complete sentence?  But "to wonder" can be both an intransitive and transitive verb.

Comment: @TBell I was saying that Stangdon's claim that *all a sentence needs to be complete is a subject and a verb* is not true.

Comment: @Divizna  Where did I say that no English verbs *must* have another complement?  All I said was that this one didn't.  You're attacking something I didn't say.

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, it's a complete sentence. It feels unnatural because it would be uncommon to see so little context provided around it, in the same vein as other short sentences like "I am running".